# QWebEngineView silently fails at loading content if QApplication execution is delayed

Tags: c++, qt5, qtwebengine

We are developing an application with a Qt UI containing a `QWebEngineView`. Currently testing on macOS (10.12..10.14) with Qt 5.9.6

Because of OS specifics, the application sometimes waits on user inputs (e.g. system admin password) before reaching the `QApplication::exec()`.
We realized that, if this wait takes too long, the `QWebEngineView::load(QUrl)` calls are silently failing, showing a grey view instead of the expected rendered html.

We created a minimal example, triggering the issue on our test environments:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWidget>

#include <chrono>    
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication qtapp(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow;
    window->setFixedSize({800, 600});
    QWebEngineView *webview = new QWebEngineView();
    window->setCentralWidget(webview);

    window->show();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    std::clog << "Done sleeping" << std::endl;

    webview->load({"https://www.google.com"});

    return qtapp.exec();
}
```

Commenting out the `sleep` Google home is rendered just fine. With the `sleep`, we get the gray area instead.

- Is there a mistake in using Qt in this example?
- Or is this a bug in the framework?

---

Edit:
Further investigation shows that the problem does not occur as long as the `sleep` is before both `webview->load()` and `window->show()`.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has an event loop that allows you to monitor various events such as the keyboard, mouse, etc. so when you use the sleep you are blocking it and consequently the GUI has frozen, if you have time-consuming tasks the strategy is to divide it into less tasks Weigh them if we can or execute it in a new thread and transmit the results to the GUI thread by means of signals. In the following example I show a simple implementation.

```
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
#include <iostream>

class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
public slots:
    void start_task(){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));
        std::clog << "Done sleeping" << std::endl;
        emit finished();
    }
signals:
    void finished();
};

class Thread final : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QThread::QThread;
    ~Thread() override {
        finish(); wait();
    }
public slots:
    void finish() {
        quit(); requestInterruption();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication qtapp(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    window.setFixedSize({800, 600});
    QWebEngineView *webview = new QWebEngineView();
    window.setCentralWidget(webview);
    window.show();
    Thread thread;
    QObject::connect(QApplication::instance(), &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &thread, &Thread::finish);
    thread.start();
    Worker worker;
    worker.moveToThread(&thread);
    QObject::connect(&worker, &Worker::finished, webview, [webview](){
        qDebug()<< "finished";
        webview->load({"https://www.google.com"});
    });
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&worker, "start_task", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    return qtapp.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```